# Finding and returning certain file names from directory

Tags: php

I have some files on a directory that are autonamed like so:

```
file.html - 7-6-14.html (this is 1 file)
file.html - 8-7-14.html
file.html - 9-6-14.html
```

There are other files in the directory, but what im trying to do is to show JUST these files. I was trying scandir & array_keys - but that wasnt working out too well. The only thing i know is that all these files will have `file.html -` in the beginning of the filename (the last part is the date the file was created). Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: A [`glob()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for something like `file.html -*.html`  will probably get you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from the [PHP: glob reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) page:

```
foreach (glob("file.html -*.html") as $filename) {
echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why posting exactly the same answer everybody has seen in comments?

Comment: Answers do not belong in comments, do they?

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Did the job! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

scandir() is the way to go.

```
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $fname) {
   if (strpos($fname, "file.html") == 0) display_file(); 
}
```

Comment: doesn't mean that someone else can't get `scandir` to work for him

Comment: He said candir() + array_keys(), which is clunky.   Note that I'm suggesting scandir() + foreach /w strpos().